# Qlik Sense Engine with Java application

Tags: java, api, integration, qliksense

My task is to integrate the Qlik sense Engine API with a Java application. I would be happy if someone suggest the steps for integration as I am starting from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Java and not javascript.

You can use JSON requests that will let you do actions to and from the Qlik Sense server and engine. You may be able to acheive what you need using the easier to understand capabilities api.

Here is the starting documentation for the engine API:

https://help.qlik.com/sense/2.1/en-us/developer/#../Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/introducing-engine-API.htm

capabilities api:

https://help.qlik.com/sense/2.1/en-us/developer/#../Subsystems/APIs/Content/mashup-api-reference.htm%3FTocPath%3DQlik%2520Sense%2520APIs%2520and%2520SDKs%7CCapability%2520APIs%7C_____0

I recommend you use the engine API explorer to get started testing what different calls do.. The API Explorer is accessible via the dev hub as described in the bottom of this post:

http://webofwork.com/the-qlik-sense-dev-hub-overview/

Here is an example of using calls to make a custom selection navigation using javascript using the capabilities API

http://webofwork.com/create-a-custom-current-selections-bar-in-qlik-sense/